# Showing $Y_{n}:=X_{n}^{1}1_{ \{\tau > n\}}+X_{n}^{2}1_{ \{\tau \leq n\}}$ is a supermartingale

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, martingales

Let $X_{n}^{1}$ and $X_{n}^{2}$ be supermartingales w.r.t $\mathbb F$ and $\tau$ a stopping time so that $X_{\tau}^{1}\geq X_{\tau}^{2}$

Show $Y_{n}:=X_{n}^{1}1_{ \{\tau > n\}}+X_{n}^{2}1_{ \{\tau \leq n\}}$ is a supermartingale

I have already shown that this is the case for $Z_{n}:=X_{n}^{1}1_{ \{\tau \geq n\}}+X_{n}^{2}1_{ \{\tau < n\}}$

My ideas for $Y$

$E[Y_{n+1}\vert \mathcal{F}_{n}]=E[X_{n+1}^{1}1_{ \{\tau > n+1\}}\vert \mathcal{F}_{n}]+E[X_{n+1}^{2}1_{ \{\tau \leq n+1\}}\vert \mathcal{F}_{n}]$

I am stuck on what to do for the first term. My ideas for the second term are as follows:
$E[X_{n+1}^{2}1_{ \{\tau \leq n+1\}}\vert \mathcal{F}_{n}]=E[X_{n+1}^{2}1_{ \{\tau < n+1\}}\vert \mathcal{F}_{n}]+E[X_{n+1}^{2}1_{ \{\tau = n+1\}}\vert \mathcal{F}_{n}]=E[X_{n+1}^{2}1_{ \{\tau \leq n\}}\vert \mathcal{F}_{n}]+E[X_{n+1}^{2}1_{ \{\tau -1 < n+1 \leq \tau\}}\vert \mathcal{F}_{n}](*)$

And I know that $\{n+1 = \tau\}=\{\tau -1 < n+1 \leq \tau\}$ is previsible since $\tau-1$ and $\tau$ are stopping times. Hence:

$(*)\leq 1_{\{\tau < n+1\}}X_{n}^{2}+1_{\{\tau=n+1\}}X_{n}^{2}=X_{n}^{2}1_{\{\tau\leq n+1\}}$

How can I manipulate the first term using the fact that $X_{\tau}^{1}\geq X_{\tau}^{2}$?

and is my assumption that $\{n+1 = \tau\}=\{\tau -1 < n+1 \leq \tau\}$ is previsible, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

\begin{alignat*}{2}
E[Y_{n+1}\vert \mathcal{F}_{n}] & = E[X_{n+1}^{2}1_{ \{\tau \le n\}}\vert \mathcal{F}_{n}] + E[X_{n+1}^{2}1_{ \{\tau = n+1\}}\vert \mathcal{F}_{n}] + E[X_{n+1}^{1}1_{ \{\tau > n+1\}}\vert \mathcal{F}_{n}]\\
& \le E[X_{n+1}^{2}1_{ \{\tau \le n\}}\vert \mathcal{F}_{n}] + E[X_{n+1}^{\color{red}{1}}1_{ \{\tau = n+1\}}\vert \mathcal{F}_{n}] + E[X_{n+1}^{1}1_{ \{\tau > n+1\}}\vert \mathcal{F}_{n}]\\
& \le E[X_{n+1}^{2}\vert \mathcal{F}_{n}]1_{ \{\tau \le n\}} + E[X_{n+1}^{1}\vert \mathcal{F}_{n}]1_{ \{\tau > n\}}\\
& \le X_{n}^{2}1_{ \{\tau \le n\}} + X_{n}^{1}1_{ \{\tau > n\}}\\
& \le Y_n
\end{alignat*}

But $\{\tau = n+1\}$ isn't predictable.

Comment: I thought if $\tau $ and $\sigma$ are bounded stopping times then $\{ \sigma < n+1 \leq \tau \}$ is predictable and hence would this not imply that $\{ \tau = n+1 \}=\{\tau -1 < n+1 \leq \tau \}$ is predictable since both $\tau$ and $\tau-1$ are bounded stopping times?

Comment: In natural language, saying that $\tau$ is $\mathcal F$-measurable means that when we know all the past until instant $n$, we can decide whether $\tau$ triggered or not before $n$. But when know that $\tau$ didn't trigger until time $n$, we cannot conclude it will trigger at $n+1$, at least, not here. Example: let $A_{n+1} = X_n^2$, then $A$ is predictable. When we know all the past until time $n$, we know $A_{n+1}$.